# Finding all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations

[image]

The answer I get for this matrix is:

$$ x_3 \left[
    \begin{array}{cc}
      4\\
      3\\1\\0
    \end{array}
\right]  +x_4\left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      0\\
      0\\0\\1
    \end{array}
\right]$$

However the answer key says that there is no second $x_4$ vector and indeed the answer only works with the first vector($x_3$). Can someone help me with this please. Thank you

My work:

[image]

Comment: This is a computational mistake that can only be pinpointed if you show how you got your answer. In any case just compute $A\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}^T$ to see that it isn't zero.

Comment: How did you get your answer?

Comment: Can you see why your answer is wrong? How did you get your answer?

Comment: Give me a minute ill put my work up

Comment: @Christoph I uploaded my answer. We havent done transpose matrices yet so if you could explain it without that it will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Your variable $x_4$ isn't free. The row $\left[\begin{matrix}0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \,|&0\end{matrix}\right]$ translates to $x_4=0$.

Comment: Double check to see if you row reduced correctly